# Mandrill API not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mandrill

I'm trying to set up the Mandrill API to send an email when a user clicks a button, but I cannot seem to get it to send. The email will send perfectly fine from the console, so I know it is not a problem with the template (Devise emails also send find).

I think it is to do with how I have set it up in the controller but I cannot find any help on where I should put it instead.

Here is the code from the controller:

```
  def attending
     @event = Event.find(params[:id])
     type = params[:type]
     if type == "attending" && @event.space != 0
        current_user.attending << @event
        @event.space = @event.space - 1
        @event.save
        AdminMailer.new_attending(@event.user, current_user)
        redirect_to :back, notice: "You've joined the group. Your number will be sent to #{@event.user.name}"

     else type == "unattending"
        current_user.attending.delete(@event)
     redirect_to :back, notice: "You've removed yourself from the group"
     end
  end
```

Here is the admin_mailer.rb

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  require 'mandrill'

  def mandrill_client
    @mandrill_client ||= Mandrill::API.new MANDRILL_API_KEY
  end

  def new_attending(creator, user)
    template_name = "new-attending"
    template_content = []
    message = {
      to: [{email: creator.email, name: creator.name}],
      subject: "Someone wants to go riding with you!",
     merge_vars: [
       {rcpt: creator.email,
       vars: [
          {name: "CREATOR_NAME", content: creator.name},
          {name: "USER_NAME", content: user.name},
          {name: "USER_NUMBER", content: user.number}
          ]}
      ]
    }
    mandrill_client.messages.send_template template_name, template_content, message
  end

end
```

And here is the link they click in the view.html.erb that should send the email:

```
 <td><% if event.user != current_user && event.space != 0 && user_signed_in? %>
     <% unless event.attendees.include?(current_user) %>
     <%= link_to "Join", attending_event_path(event, type: "attending"), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs", method: :put %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %></td>
```

Any help in figuring out why it's not sending would be great! As I said, it works in the console when I type:

```
AdminMailer.new_attending(@event, @user)
```

Comment: Have you tried by doing this `AdminMailer.new_attending(@event.user, current_user).deliver` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace following code.

```
AdminMailer.new_attending(@event.user, current_user)
```

with

```
AdminMailer.new_attending(@event.user, current_user).deliver
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Changing the code to Amit's suggestion did work but apparently Rails would prefer using .deliver_now or .deliver_later as it is more specific...